# displaying waveform in xcode

Tags: xcode, audio, record, waveform, caf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [rendering a waveform on an iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896194/rendering-a-waveform-on-an-iphone)
>   [Efficient method to draw a line with millions of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849076/efficient-method-to-draw-a-line-with-millions-of-points)

Can anyone please help me with displaying the waveform of an audio file in xcode?

Actually, I've recorded an audio through AVAudioRecorder class. Now, I want to get the waveform of this either while the audio is being recorded OR use the .caf file it saved.

Please?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you want XCode(IDE) to draw waveform for your audiofile ? Do you want your application to draw waveform for Audio file, if yes is it MAC Application or iOS application ?

Comment: I'm assuming by AVAudioRecorder that you're talking about an iOS application here, but I could be wrong, given that Lion has that class now as well.  In any case, the linked question has answers that point to solutions for this that would work on both platforms.

Comment: well, actually i need to extract the PCM of an audio file.yes this is for iOS.