# Visualize Audio Data with Cbjective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, view, data-visualization

In my view I need to visualize some audio data as waveform. I also want to make pinch-zoom in/out possible. how could that be realized? Is there any knowledge around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the audio sample data, I use [the approach here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849076/efficient-method-to-draw-a-line-with-millions-of-points/4849784#4849784).

To display more or less samples than points, use interpolation or the peak sample value. Reserve a lot of time for optimization if you want good performance over many samples.